# GridView control is assigned data correctly but it doesn't display it

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a method inside a separate class that returns a GridView but for some reason it will not display the data.  After further investigation, I found that Gridview has been assigned the correct data but does not display it!  If I run the code inside the main class it works fine!  Please help!

//Vinyl class

```
public GridView SearchByAlbum(string AlbumName)
{
    VinylComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    VinylComm.CommandText = "AlbumVinylSearch";

    SqlParameter VinylAlbumName;
    VinylAlbumName = new SqlParameter();
    VinylAlbumName.ParameterName = "@AlbumName";
    VinylAlbumName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    VinylAlbumName.SqlValue = AlbumName;
    VinylAlbumName.Size = 50;
    VinylAlbumName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    VinylComm.Parameters.Add(VinylAlbumName);

    GridView gv;
    gv = new GridView();

    VinylConn.Open();
    gv.DataSource = VinylComm.ExecuteReader();
    gv.DataBind();
    VinylConn.Close();

    return gv;
}
```

//Main Page

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Vinyl v;
    v = new Vinyl();
    switch (SearchOptions.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            GridView1 = v.SearchByAlbum(SearchInput.Text);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your variable names should start with lowercase. See the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> the Gridview knows it has the data but does not want to display it

Naughty `GridView`. Instead of creating dynamic `GridViews` and assign the reference to another GridView which is already in your page, you should simply return the `DataSource`. That does not even work, it is also more reusable  if you want that data somewhere else.

```
switch (SearchOptions.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        GridView1.DataSource = v.SearchByAlbum(SearchInput.Text);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and the method which loads and returns the data:

```
public IDataSource SearchByAlbum(string AlbumName)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That won't work on account of the connection being a part of the Vinyl class. Are you suggesting that I have to put the connection on the main page?

Comment: @user1993880: No, you just have to change the signature of `SearchByAlbum` to return the data instead of the `GridView`. You load it there as before. You can return your `DataReader` or a `DataTable`, `IEnumerable<CustomClass>` or whatever.

Comment: You can't DataBind outside of the connection though.  I get an error: "Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed."

Comment: @user1993880: Return a `DataTable`(use a `DataAdapter` to fill it) or `IEnumerable<CustomClass>` instead. You could create a class `Album` and return a `List<Album>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on a previous answer, I completely agree that you should pass the source of the data from your Vinyl class yo your DataSource:

```
GridView1.DataSource = v.SearchByAlbum(SearchInput.Text);
```

However, I would suggest returning a `List<yourObject>` or `IEnumerable` from your SearchByAlbum procedure.  I think your DAL and your UI should be independent on each other.  That's where introducing Models (or DTOs) can help alleviate the pain of changes down the road.

Something like this:

```
public class yourobject {
   int id { get; set; }
   string anyotherprop { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Vinyl class (just copying from above, but some could be consolidated -- you should use using for example, but that's another subject):

```
public List<yourobject> SearchByAlbum(string AlbumName)
{
    List<yourobject> yourobjects = new List<yourobject>();

    VinylComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    VinylComm.CommandText = "AlbumVinylSearch";

    SqlParameter VinylAlbumName;
    VinylAlbumName = new SqlParameter();
    VinylAlbumName.ParameterName = "@AlbumName";
    VinylAlbumName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    VinylAlbumName.SqlValue = AlbumName;
    VinylAlbumName.Size = 50;
    VinylAlbumName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    VinylComm.Parameters.Add(VinylAlbumName);

    VinylConn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = VinylComm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yourobjects.Add(new yourobject() { 
           //Fill values
        });
    }
    VinylConn.Close();

    return yourobjects;
}
```

Also, if using in other Gridview procedures (RowDataBound, RowCommand, etc.), I think you'll find it easier to Cast your objects as well.

Good luck.

Comment: I knew of this possibility but I thought it would save me some time if I just returned a GridView.  Lazy man works twice as hard :)